# How to understand "rake db:seed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, seed, dbmigrate

I am using Michael Hartl's rails tutorials.
Whenever I use the following

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset
```

Then

```
$ bundle exec rake db:seed
```

> It waits. It doesn't show anything.

And when I do:

```
bundle exec rake test
```

I get

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError: Migrations are pending.
To resolve this issue, 
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

> When the above is done-"db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test", tests are clear.

However Michael doesn't mention anything happening about this scenario, Can anybody help and explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, most `rake` commands are going to run in the context of the `RAILS_ENV` passed to the command line.  If no `RAILS_ENV` is passed to the command line, it will run in the `development` context, which is separate from the `test` context.  There are a few exceptions, like `rake db:create`, which will create your `development` and `test` databases, but `migrate` will work against the specified environment.

Comment: You mean, I will not have a database in the test environment unless explicitly migrated?

Comment: Your database will be there, but the migrations - the things that define all of your tables and columns and such - will not be there.